# How do I get to next element with a keyPressed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to go to the next section with the function keyPressed() for a presentation view I like to do this without a framework like jQuery.

to call the method:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    keyPressed();
}

var onPage=3;
function keyPressed(){
    let sections = document.getElementByTag("section");
    onPage++;
    GOTO: sections[onPage] //the href in the a element would be "../#sectionJJ"
}
```

And in my html there is:

```
<section>content 1 <section>
<section>content 2<section>
<section>content 3<section>
<section id="section4JJ">content 4<section>
<section>content 5<section>
```

Comment: well how do you go to it? scroll, show, url, etc.....

Comment: what is `sections` and how onPage is related to next element?

Comment: the GOTO: Sections[onPage] doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 an element `id` can be used as an anchor. And the way to jump around is to literally navigate to `#section4JJ`. `window.location` to the rescue. For legacy browsers, [you must include an](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) `<a name="section4JJ"></a>` for example.

If you hit `yourpage.html#section4JJ` and the page is long enough, you will notice it will jump. So here is a working example:

```js
var onPage = 0;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(){
    var sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
 if(onPage < sections.length - 1){
  onPage++;
  
  //GOTO: sections[onPage] //the href in the a element would be "../#sectionJJ"
  window.location = '#' + sections[onPage].id;
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<section id="sectionABC"><h1>content 1</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></section>
<section id="sectionDEF"><h1>content 2</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></section>
<section id="sectionXUV"><h1>content 3</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></section>
<section id="section4JJ"><h1>content 4</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></section>
<section id="section5FF"><h1>content 5</h1><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></section>

</body>
</html>
```